# How to loop using result from json_decode()?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I got JSON like this:

```
$json = '{"message":"{\"Code\":\"402\",\"Message\":\"Failed register new customer\",\"result\":\"Customer Name Already Exisist, \\r\\nSilakan Hubungi IT Untuk Proses Selanjutnya.\"}"}';
```

I decode this JSON like this:

```
$msg = json_encode(json_decode($json,true)['message']);
```

and the result is:

```
"{\"Code\":\"402\",\"Message\":\"Failed register new customer\",\"result\":\"Customer Name Already Exisist, \r\nSilakan Hubungi IT Untuk Proses Selanjutnya.\"}"
```

Now, I'd like to decode it again to get the `Code` and `result`.

```
    $new_json = json_decode($msg,true);
    
    echo $new_json->Code;
```

It give me `Message: Trying to get property 'Code' of non-object`

How do I get the `Code` and `result`?

Comment: Why do you `json_encode` it again? Just… don't. And decide whether you're going to use object `->` or array `[]` access and be consistent.

Comment: to make it a string again

Comment: It's a bit unclear whether `message` is another JSON string inside your JSON and needs to be decoded again or not, since your first snippet is invalid PHP syntax…

Comment: And why do you want to make it a string again?

Comment: to store it in DB and then decode it again to get the `Code` and `result`

Comment: Well, from the looks of it, you have a JSON string inside a JSON string. So `json_decode($json, true)['message']` already is a JSON string. No need to encode that again.

Comment: I've removed the `json_encode`. How do i get the `Code` and `result` ?

Comment: `echo $new_json['Code'], $new_json['result']`?

Comment: still showing `Message: Illegal string offset 'Code'`

Comment: `<?php

$json_1 = '{"name" : "test"}';

$a = json_decode($json_1, true);

var_dump($a);
echo $a['name'];


$json_2 = json_encode($a);

echo $json_2;`

Comment: It turns out I have these character in my JSON `\\r\\n` and it break the JSON